# Conditional and ifs + prefix/suffix

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have something like this:

[image: Conditional and pre]

In each E cell, I would like to return the D number of that row, as long as certain conditions are fulfilled, with the prefix $ if C2=$, and suffix € if C2=€.

I have this but it's not working at all (despite it is wrong, it probably can help you understand what I need):

```
=IF(A2="","",IFS(if(C2="$",OR(B2="Buy",B2="Sell"),"$"&D2,if(C2="€",OR(B2="Buy",B2="Sell"),D2&"€"))))
```

I'm sorry if I just posted something really awful, I tried...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cell E2 you can use:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"",OR(B2="Buy",B2="Sell")),SWITCH(C2,"$",C2&D2,"€",D2&C2,""),"")
```

And drag / copy-paste the formula to the remaining rows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Carlos, that is exactly what I'be been trying to achieve!

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything from Column E including the header. Then try placing this in E1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IF(C2:C="$",C2:C&D2:D,D2:D&C2:C)))`

Understand that once you "stick" the "$" or "€" to the numbers from Column D, they will not longer be numbers capable of having math performed on them. Rather, they will become strings. Maybe that won't matter to your application, since you already have the number values in Column D; but I figured you should know this.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that is also good. It'll certainly be useful in what I'm doing! Thanks!!

Comment: @markens,  I see that you want the Euro symbol after the number. Simple enough fix. I updated my formula.